# How can we calculate optimal dimensions for volume of transformer?

Tags: transformer

I have to design a transformer. First of all, I did calculations for the core that is available in the market. Now I want to optimize the volume of the transformer core and wanted to design my custom transformer?

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. What is your question, specifically?

Comment: And show your user requirement specifications and calculations so far. We don't know whether you're thinking of 5 W or 2 MW transformer and single or three-phase.

Comment: Note that:$$ \left(volume = l_e\cdot A_c\right) \ge \frac{\mu_0\: \mu_r\: I_{peak}}{B_{max}^{\:2}} \int H\:~\textrm{d} B$$Given the AC voltage and its frequency and your core material you can work it out. Optimization is a different issue, though, and involves tradeoffs on wire diameter, length of wire, the area available for your windings, winding method, etc. Optimization is a bit of an art.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your question is about "how to optimize the design of a transformer with a specific set of constraints in order to minimize the function **Volume**".

I have tried several methods of design optimization. Methods such as [Gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) are generally not applicable, as variables (such as wire gauge) are not continuous functions, moreover, it is not your case, but often the optimization needs to be multi-objective. In my experience, stochastic methods such as [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) are more effective and easy-to-implement.

Anyway, unfortunately there will be no single answer to your question. If you don't want to spend too much time developing a tool for this, you can try various design configurations manually with the core models available on the market. After a few tries, you can already get an idea of how the optimization algorithms would work on your problem.